# Does <algorithm> define a macro X?

Tags: c++, algorithm, gcc, stl

I tried to compile [the code](http://cpp.sh/8vrep) with option C++14:

```
#define X static_cast<double>(2)
#include <algorithm>
// if you change the two lines, no error occurs

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

But I get error after X:

> error: expected ',' or '...'

I do not get error with option C++98. With my gcc version 4.8.4, I don't get error, but with 5.4.0 I do. Is this a bug? Do I do something wrong?

Comment: No error with gcc6

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/g/Xv0ksm) with provided code. As for whether <algorithm> defines a macro, you can check the documentation - it doesn't.

Comment: That's why I provided the link. If it is a bug, than the provider linked may use the affected versions. So @DeiDei, is it a bug and I did everything fine? If so, please make an answer to accept it.

Comment: g++ 5.1.0 same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I get the same error on my local g++ 5.4.0 installation.  I looked at the `g++ -E` output, and it seems the error traces to /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/ia32intrin.h lines 252 and 254:

```
/* Write flags register */
extern __inline void
__attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
__writeeflags (unsigned long long X) // 252
{
  __builtin_ia32_writeeflags_u64 (X); // 254
}
```

This can be considered a bug in the compiler-bundled library, since non-reserved `#define`s are not supposed to conflict with them.  (Other functions in the same header use parameter `__X`.)

Comment: This is why the preprocessor is evil.

Comment: That is a bug. Standard library must not use any identifiers except reserved ones exactly because of this issue. Stephan T. Lavavej once gave a passionate monologue about lengths they have to go in STL implementation to make sure it works in all the corner cases (they assume users are evil and will do every weird thing allowed within the standard; they are not wrong). User-defined macros are easy to deal with (just don't use names like X); user-defined types with overloaded operators inflict more pain.

Comment: This raises an interesting question.  Is there a way to protect my _own_ headers from such user-defined macro issues?

Comment: Fixed in GCC 7.1 by https://gcc.gnu.org/r239617 and will also be fixed in GCC 6.4